# Why can't i apply the translator while iterating through a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, google-translate, python-packaging

I have information stored in a list of dictionaries - listdic, and need to translate stuff stored under keys. However, it gives me the error: 'Translated' object is not iterable

This is google translate package. I tried another one - translate, which worked this way, but it has a limited amount of characters to be translated, so it does not suit me.

```py
translator= Translator()
for y in listdic:
    title0=y['title']
    trt = translator.translate(title0,src='ru',dest='en')
    y['title']=trt
    description0=y['description']
    trd = translator.translate(description0,src='ru',dest='en')
    y['description']=trd
    text0=y['text']
    trtext = translator.translate(text0,src='ru',dest='en')
    y['text']=trtext

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-e9bc70b521f4> in <module>
      2 for y in listdic:
      3     title0=y['title']
----> 4     trt = translator.translate(title0,src='ru',dest='en')
      5     y['title']=trt
      6     description0=y['description']

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
     73             text = text.decode('utf-8')
     74 
---> 75         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     76         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     77                                     token=token)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    199     def do(self, text):
    200         self._update()
--> 201         tk = self.acquire(text)
    202         return tk

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py in acquire(self, text)
    144         a = []
    145         # Convert text to ints
--> 146         for i in text:
    147             val = ord(i)
    148             if val < 0x10000:

TypeError: 'Translated' object is not iterable
```

I expect this code to return an updated list of dictionaries with translated data.

Comment: why do you have listdic on the bottom of the code? Also, if you post the full error message it could be useful

Comment: i have it to see what the dictionary looks like. nevermind. yes, i will post it

Comment: are you sure that there are no duplicates in the list?

Comment: yes, i am sure about that

Comment: What happens if you create a new dictionary, instead of overwriting the existing one?

Comment: Just tried, the same thing happens